# 2 Unique RAND() items from database

Tags: php, sql, random, unique

At present im using:

```
SELECT * from foo ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```

to select 2 random items from database but there is the possiblily of the result both being the same item so how can i make it so they are not and both always different?

As always thanks in advance :)

Comment: No, with this you will never get the same item twice. It will always be two different records.

Comment: The same row will not occur twice in the result. If this is not what you mean by 'the same item', please clarify.

Comment: Ah problem solved after reading your comment I double checked the database and the error is there 2 of the same items ...thank you mischa and Ramon

Answer (score 2):

**Using `ORDER BY RAND()` does not result in duplicate rows.**

Judging from scattered forum posts and [bug reports](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/203256), this might have been the case in a previous MySQL version (although I strongly doubt this), but it definitely is not anymore. I have just run a couple of tests myself and can confirm that `ORDER BY RAND()` should never return duplicate rows.